# Excel formula for multiple partners buying out another partner

Tags: partnership

I am in a partnership that was originally 8 people:

1. Partner A owned 19.9%
2. Partner B Owned 19.9%
3. Partner C Owned 19.9%
4. Partner D Owned 19.9%
5. Partner E Owned 5.1%
6. Partner F Owned 5.1%
7. Partner G Owned 5.1%
8. Partner H Owned 5.1%

First calculation is when Partner H decided to sell his 5.1% of ownership to the other partners.
How do you calculate on an excel spreadsheet the percentage amount each of the remaining partners would receive.

Second calculation is when Partner G decides to sell Her 5.1% ownership.  How do you calculate on an excel spreadsheet the percentage amount that each partner would now own?

Answer (score 5):

> First calculation is when Partner H decided to sell his 5.1% of ownership to the other partners. How do you calculate on an excel spreadsheet the percentage amount each of the remaining partners would receive.

Not clear when you say partners would receive. Partners would need to pay Partner H some money for his share.

If the idea is everyone pays the same amount; then you simply divide 5.1 by 7 [0.728571429]. So on the final price agreed, every pays same amount to Partner H. It would mean Partners having a share of 19.9 will after this have 20.62857% and Partners having 5.1% would have 5.828571.

If on the other hand you need the remaining partners to own in the same proportion to current ownership; Then divide 5.1% in ratio of sum of other ownership. i.e. Excluding H; the ownership is 94.9%. So to find the proportion; you calculate 19.9[Ownership of Partner A]*5.1[Ownership of Partner H]/94.9 [Ownership of remaining partners]. So for partners holding 19.9 this will be 1.069442 and increase their ownership to 20.96944152 and for partners holding 5.1% it would be 0.274077977 increasing ownership to 5.374077977

> Second calculation is when Partner G decides to sell Her 5.1% ownership.

Same as above.